# failed to create new connection: desc = transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.19.0.4:9051: connect: connection refused Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Can anyone help me fixing below error. I'm trying to install chaincode on peer via cli. I configured cli container correctly. But somehow Im getting this error..

```
grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = “transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup peer0.org1.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: connection refused
```

Here is my [docker-compose-cli.yaml](https://gist.github.com/ethdev279/e516c1e21fbac5d6f8f9596ef5dd2809)

Answer (score 0):

You can run into odd DNS resolution issues depending on the configuration of DNS on your host system.  The easiest thing to try is to add the `dns_search` config value to your Compose file:

```
cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    dns_search: .
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916717/6160507 as well ... you might need this for all of your services.

Comment: I am also get same issue with k8s cluster, @Gari Singh do you have any solution for that? I have tried above solution however its give error as dns search not allow

Comment: I try with IP address (localhost and 0.0.0.0 and container IP) but the same error occurs, I think it does not depend on DNS @Gari Singh.

Answer (score -1):

solution 1 :
use the command: **sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8"** and start once again

Solution 2 : check your container logs and see

use the command **"docker logs container-id"**

Solution 3 :add "dns_serach: ." in docker-compose.yaml file and start
once again as below

**
dns_search: .
**